# Ternary operators in Meteor

Tags: meteor, ternary-operator, meteorite, spacebars

I am using Meteoris for working on my application. I have this scenario in forms. This is an edit view and I am just showing two of the 17 fields I have here:

```
<label for="name" class="control-label">Name *</label>
<input type="text" id="name" value="{{profile.name}}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
<label for="acctType" class="control-label">Account Type</label>
<select id="acctType" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1" {{(profile.acctType == 1) ? 'selected="selected"' : ""}}>Free</option>
    <option value="2" {{(profile.acctType == 2) ? 'selected="selected"' : ""}}>Paid</option>
</select>
```

I have a Name field and an Account Type field. For the Account Type, I have numeric values stored in the Mongo DB. When I try to check something like this, Okay, I am a PHP Developer, and in PHP I do this:

```
<label for="name" class="control-label">Name *</label>
<input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $profile_name; ?>" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
<label for="acctType" class="control-label">Account Type</label>
<select id="acctType" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1"<?php echo ($profile_acctType == 1) ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Free</option>
    <option value="2"<?php echo ($profile_acctType == 2) ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Paid</option>
</select>
```

I was getting the following errors. When I didn't give any spaces between `"` and `{`, I was getting:

```
While building the application:
client/views/users/profile.html:42: Expected space
...    <option value="1"{{(profile.acctType ...
```

And when I tried giving a space, I got this error:

```
While building the application:
client/views/users/profile.html:42: Expected IDENTIFIER
... <option value="1" {{(profile.acctType ==...
```

What is your advice on fixing this issue?

Comment: do you have all the possible account types stored in a mongo document or meteor collection? Becuase instead of manually writing out each <option> I would use an {{#each}} tag to loop through the account types. Then you can use something like [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected) to do a conditional check.

Comment: Oh... Not in collection for now. Hardcoded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With more info about your end goal I could make something more eloquent, but here's an option

```
Template.blah.helpers({
    isAccountType: function (acctType) {
        if (user.profile.acctType === acctType) return 'selected'
    }
});
<option value="1" {{isAccountType 1}}>Free</option>
```

Comment: Do I need to use a helper for such a small thing?

Comment: Yes, but for good reason. It moves a lot of the logic outside of the HTML file which, IMHO (as a front-end developer), makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, lemme try and will set you know.

Comment: Nopes... Shows some unbound error... Anyways, is it possible to use a comparison helper, that takes two arguments?

Comment: As Ramsay said, it's a good idea to keep business logic outside of content. Meteor doesn't enforce MVC, but it's *strongly* encouraged. I updated my code to fix the syntax so it should work. You can pass as many args as you want, it's just javascript, after all. I don't know how you could get an unbound error...i didn't think those existed in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use {{#if key==val}} in templates but you can do smth like this to get your problem done:

1. Set in session your profile data `Session.set("profile_acctType", 2)`, you can specify this in your template helpers when you get user profile.
2. When "yourTemplate" is rendered select the value:

   `Template['yourTemplate'].rendered = function(){
         $("#acctType").val(Session.get("profile_acctType"));
       }`

Comment: This is not in templates.

Comment: @PraveenKumar your html is not in a template ? O_o

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for the answers. What I did was:

```
Template.blah.helpers({
    getSelected: function (acctType, currentValue) {
        if (currentValue == acctType) return 'selected'
    }
});
```

And in the form, I did this way:

```
<option value="1" {{getSelected profile.acctType "1"}}>Free</option>
<option value="2" {{getSelected profile.acctType "2"}}>Paid</option>
```

Did a generic helper. Could help someone. `:)`